# Why is libc++'s vector<bool>::const_reference not bool?

Tags: c++, vector, std, libc++, std-bitset

Section 23.3.7 Class `vector<bool>` [vector.bool], paragraph 1 states:

```
template <class Allocator> class vector<bool, Allocator> {
public:
    // types:
    typedef bool              const_reference;
    ...
```

However this program fails to compile when using libc++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int
main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::vector<bool>::const_reference, bool>{}, "?");
}
```

Furthermore I note that the C++ standard has been consistent in this specification all the way back to C++98.  And I further note that libc++ has consistently not followed this specification since the first introduction of libc++.

What is the motivation for this non-conformance?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The motivation for this extension, which is detectable by a conforming program, and thus non-conforming, is to make `vector<bool>` behave more like `vector<char>` with respect to references (const and otherwise).

**Introduction**

Since 1998, `vector<bool>` has been derided as "not quite a container."  [LWG 96](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#96), one of the very first LWG issues, launched the debate.  Today, 17 years later, `vector<bool>` remains largely unchanged.

[This paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html) goes into some specific examples on how the behavior of `vector<bool>` differs from every other instantiation of `vector`, thus hurting generic code.  However the same paper discusses at length the very nice performance properties `vector<bool>` can have if properly implemented.

*Summary*:  `vector<bool>` isn't a bad container. It is actually quite useful.  It just has a bad name.

**Back to `const_reference`**

As introduced above, and [detailed here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html), what is bad about `vector<bool>` is that it behaves differently in generic code than other `vector` instantiations.  Here is a concrete example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void
test(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    using const_ref = typename std::vector<T>::const_reference;
    const std::vector<T>& cv = v;
    const_ref cr = cv[0];
    assert(cr == cv[0]);
    v[0] = 1;
    assert(true == cv[0]);
    assert(cr == cv[0]);  // Fires!
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<char> vc(1);
    test(vc);
    std::vector<bool> vb(1);
    test(vb);
}
```

The standard specification says that the assert marked `// Fires!` will trigger, but only when `test` is run with a `vector<bool>`.  When run with a `vector<char>` (or any `vector` besides `bool` when an appropriate non-default `T` is assigned), the test passes.

The libc++ implementation sought to minimize the negative effects of having `vector<bool>` behave differently in generic code.  One thing it did to achieve this is to make  `vector<T>::const_reference` a *proxy-reference*, just like the specified `vector<T>::reference`, except that you can't assign through it.  That is, on libc++, `vector<T>::const_reference` is essentially a pointer to the bit inside the `vector`, instead of a copy of that bit.

On libc++ the above `test` passes for both `vector<char>` and `vector<bool>`.

**At what cost?**

The downside is that this extension is detectible, as shown in the question.  However, very few programs actually care about the exact type of this alias, and more programs care about the behavior.

> What is the motivation for this non-conformance?

To give the libc++ client better behavior in generic code, and perhaps after sufficient field testing, propose this extension to a future C++ standard for the betterment of the entire C++ industry.

Such a proposal might come in the form of a new container (e.g. `bit_vector`) that has much the same API as today's `vector<bool>`, but with a few upgrades such as the `const_reference` discussed here.  Followed by deprecation (and eventual removal) of the `vector<bool>` specialization.  `bitset` could also use a little upgrading in this department, e.g. add `const_reference`, and a set of iterators.

That is, in hindsight `bitset` is to `vector<bool>` (which should be renamed to `bit_vector` -- or whatever), as `array` is to `vector`.  And the analogy ought to hold true whether or not we are talking about `bool` as the `value_type` of `vector` and `array`.

There are multiple examples of C++11 and C++14 features that started out as extensions in libc++.  This is how standards evolve.  Actual *demonstrated* **positive** field experience carries strong influence.  The standards folk are a conservative bunch when it comes to changing existing specifications (as they should be).  Guessing, even when you are sure you are guessing correctly, is a risky strategy for evolving an internationally recognized standard.

Comment: Question: could/would the recent [draft proposal](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D0022.html) on proxy iterators by @EricNiebler somehow legitimize the libc++ extensions and put `vector<bool>` on a more first-class footing?

Comment: Remark: I'd prefer to have a `vector_bool<Alloc>` and an `array_bool<N>` to represent packed versions (including random-access proxy iterators iterating all bits) of `vector<bool, Alloc>` and `array<bool, N>`. However, `bitset<N>` (and it's cousin `boost::dynamic_bitset<Alloc>`) represent a different abstraction: namely packed versions of `std::set<int>`. So I'd like to have, say, `bit_array<N>` and `bit_vector<Alloc>` to be the successors to the bitset franchise, with appropriate *bidirectional* iterators (iterating over the 1-bits, rather than over all bits). What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: My draft proposal on proxy iterators would make `vector<bool>` a std-conforming random-access container. It wouldn't make `vector<bool>` a good idea. :-) I agree with Howard. It should have been called something else.

Comment: Why isn't there a way to opt out of libc++ extensions and get strictly conforming behavior? (I'm not even asking for making conformance the default, just a way to disable libc++'s extensions to be able to write portable code). As you know I was bitten by libc++ tuple extensions in the past, and recently bitten by the bitset::const_reference extension.

Comment: @gnzlbg:  A finite amount of economic and temporal resources were available for the initial development of libc++.  Subsequently the implementation was doomed to not make every single user happy.  Given available resources, engineering tradeoffs were made in an attempt to maximize the number of happy users, maximize benefit to the overall C++ community.  Sorry about your experience.  I note that the tuple extensions that you ran afoul of are now in the current C++1z working paper.  On that issue, you unknowingly sacrificed so that many could benefit, and those many owe you a debt of gratitude.